# Is it possible to run a single doctest in Django using "manage.py test"

Tags: python, django, doctest

In my Django app, I have a mix of doctests (defined in models.py and views.py) and unit tests (defined in tests.py.  I can invoke an individual unit test by doing:

```
manage.py test app.TestCase
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for the doctests. Is there some way to run a single doctest (defined in models.py or views.py)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a small script that lets you run doctests in a specific file or module in your project. Running doctests from a specific file or module: [LINK](http://dodrum.blogspot.com/2011/01/running-doctests-in-django-project.html).

It makes sure that the correct testing environment is loaded (emulating what manage.py test does). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think the way python doctests work is to simply run all doctests in a module in the same interpreter instance.

I doubt that manage.py can alter that basic behavior of python doctests.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
python -m doctest views.py
```